# What's the difference between Grid.Row and Grid.RowSpan?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

When i created a grid row in grid, i notice in my other controls has two new properties Grid.Row and Grid.Row Span.What is the different between those two?

Comment: Have you tried to read MSDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Row` as the name implies, is the row in which your element will be placed. `RowSpan` is the number of rows that it will further occupy. For example, a control with `Grid.Row=3` and `Grid.RowSpan=4` will be placed in 4th row (index starts with zero) and will go up to 7th row.